# Are the questions which ask about "What to do?" and "Doing something worthy or not?" for a given situation, bad questions for SE?

Tags: discussion

Please examine the question patterns below:

- I am in so and so situation. The details of the situation is so and so. Additional details are so and so. Now what to do? In order to find answer for my question, I have done so and so. For example, *The application is taking too much time while fetching more than 100 records. What to do now?*
- The details of the situation is so and so. Based on so and so reason I feel that doing so and so. Is it worthy to do that? In order to find answer for my question, I have done so and so. For example *The application is taking too much time while fetching more than 100 records. Is it worthy to use connection pooling mechanism to improve speed?*

In the above given situations in

(a) User is asking about what to do

and in

(b) He is asking whether doing something is worthy or not.

My specific question is asking about "What to do?" and "worthy to do some thing?" becomes bad question in SE? If yes, please explain me to why?

**Research I have done:**
I tried to search in the MSO to find answer. But the results are not relevant to my question.

Comment: It's tough to follow your hypothetical examples.  Could you link to some real examples of the type of question you're referring to?

Comment: Too many "so and so"s. Do you mean questions that ask whether a certain approach to solving a problem is advisable?

Comment: @ramya, you should probably use "such and such" instead of "so and so", but I didn't bother changing that.  I still don't understand what you want though, so I wasn't able to clean up the penultimate question at the end.

Comment: @OP: "Worthy": You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: @Telthien I think you mean you do not think it means what *you think* they think it means (I think). Do you think what I think you mean?

Comment: @Asad I think you think what I think I mean when you think about my thinking.

Answer (score 6):

What I believe you're asking about is the distinction between opening a discussion about the appropriate path, and asking a question about how to proceed with a given path.

My response to this would be: If a user asks a good question (e.g. one which proposes an issue with a given path), but words it such that it could be interpreted as a discussion, the answers will all pertain to solving the issue presented, and the users will answer the question as such.

Of course, there is a borderline between asking a specific question and asking a generic discussion about an approach. I think, in this case, user moderation is the best approach. This is the fundamental philosophy of StackExchange, and I think the systems provided are effective in this regard.

If a question is too vague, or is clearly intended to open a discussion, it will be flagged. Otherwise, even if the wording could be interpreted as a question, the users will answer the given issue.

To apply your (admittedly slightly unclear) wording, if a user is asking whether something is a worthy path, and presents an issue with it, the issue will be solved. However, if it's simply discussion, it will be closed.

Edit: The example you've given is a question on Meta. Meta is inherently a place for discussion about StackExchange, and thus the question will be discussion-based. Your example even has the `discussion` tag.

Comment: I think you have correctly interpreted this.  Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't understand all that you want in an answer, I can say that questions on the "worth" of something completely depend on the context.  If you're talking about SEO or User Interfaces, then "worth" is a pretty important concept.